# Restrict the back button for all browser in a React Application

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to restrict the back button in a react SPA for all browsers.
I have tried the following code inside componentDidMount() & even tried on the window load function.

```
window.history.pushState(null, null, window.location.href);
window.onpopstate = function () {
  window.history.go(1);
};
```

**It's working on Firefox & Safari, but not working on Chrome.**

Comment: Please don't implement a dark pattern like this. If a user arrives at your SPA from another site, he/she cannot navigate away using the Back feature.

Comment: A good UI Developer should know that this is a horrible practice. I would say think about a better solution for your problem instead of implementing such dark patterns.